# How to to design button in responsive to screen width

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I want to code a screen size responsive button that will resize itself according to screen size in Javascript.
I can make it in css3 but I want the Javascript coding.

Comment: What's your HTML code?

Comment: why do you want it in JS? What's wrong with a CSS solution? Generally with most things especially related to layout, if you can do it in CSS it's preferable. Are you facing some specific issue with the CSS version? Also...this is not just a free write-my-code service, sorry. We'll _help_ you with a specific issue in your code, but you are expected make a bit of effort yourself to research and try to implement what you want. Then if you get stuck, we can assist.

Comment: I am Doing a website project and the button connects the page to a third-party app. So The Code That I got Is In Javascript So I just want to Modify the button to responsive

Answer (score 0):

I used navigator.userAgent to detect the browser, if it helps you

To get screen height, width you can use:

screen.availWidth
screen.availHeight

or

window.innerWidth <-- but it depends on window size

```js
function isMobile() {
  return (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
}

function loadScript(url) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = url;
  head.appendChild(script);
}

if (isMobile()) {
  console.log("mobile");
} else {
  console.log("desktop");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you prefer js instead of css but you can do it like this:

```
// lets say your button's id is btn
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';

window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
  btn.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
}, false);
```

Comment: Okay I am Doing A project on my Website and I have the Code In Javascript that connects the button to a third-party app so the code goes like this---